# Generate attachment for email in PowerBuilder

Tags: powerbuilder, ghostscript, datawindow

I want to send a mail using Lotus Notes in PowerBuilder. I also want to have a attachment to the mail to be sent.
However the content to be placed in the attachment is taken from a stored procedure.
The attachment is a pdf attachment. Therefore we are using Ghostscript for that purpose.
Can we directly create a attachment of the data received from stored procedure.
Or we have to first pull the data into a DataWindow and then create an attachment of that DataWindow.
Or is there any alternate solution?
Can anyone please guide me through this?
I am totally new to PowerBuilder.

Regards,
Prathamesh

Comment: 1. How many users do you have.
2. Are the workstations under the control of your IT department?
This information is important because the most straightforward way to implement this is difficult to support outside of a corporate IT infrastructure.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?  I am currently experiencing the same issue!

Answer (score 0):

The method which I used to generate apdf attachment in powerbuilder is through the datawindow. First I pull all the data into a datawindow and then generate a pdf attachment of that datawindow Code is as below

```
n_ds ds_data 
ds_data = CREATE n_ds ds_data.DataObject = "d_co_escalation"
ds_data.of_SetTransObject(SQLCA)
ds_data.Object.DataWindow.Export.PDF.Method = Distill! 
ds_data.Object.DataWindow.Printer = "Sybase DataWindow PS" 
ds_data.Object.DataWindow.Export.PDF.Distill.CustomPostScript ="Yes"
```